# JavaFX and Table View - First time selection won't work

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am developing simple JavaFX application. In my main view I have Table View. On row select method selectedEmployeeDetails() is called. It fills Labels which show details of employee (name, lastname..etc). When I start my app and select first row (only first row) nothing is happening. When I select secound row everything is fine. Then when I select first row again everyting works normal. Here is my code inside initialize method of main view's controller.

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {

      dialog.setMaximized();
      dialog.setTitle("Test");

      this.employeeModel.loadData();
      employees = this.employeeModel.getEmployees();
      employeeTableView.setItems(employees); 

      this.employeeFirstName.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("name"));
      this.employeeFirstName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

      this.employeeLastName.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("lastname"));
      this.employeeLastName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

      this.employeeFatherClmn.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("fathersName"));
      this.employeeFatherClmn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

      this.employeeJmbgClmn.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("jmbg"));
      this.employeeJmbgClmn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

      this.employeeContractClmn.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("contractType"));
      this.employeeContractClmn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

      this.employeePositionClmn.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("position"));
      this.employeePositionClmn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

      this.employeeStatusClmn.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Employee, String>("status"));
      this.employeeStatusClmn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

      //employeeTableView.getColumns().addAll(employeeFirstName, employeeLastName);


      selectedEmployeeDetails(null);

      //Add change listener
      employeeTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
             //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
              if (employeeTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {

                    selectedEmployeeDetails(newValue);
                     System.out.println(employeeTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
              }
              else
              {
                 System.out.println("EROR");
              }

     });

}
```

Can someone help me to see what is the main reason my first row wont fire selectedEmployeeDetails() method on first time select.

**EDIT**

```
private void selectedEmployeeDetails(Employee employee)
    {

        if(employee != null)
        {
            this.employeeDetailLastname.setText(employee.getLastname());
            this.emloyeeDetailFathersName.setText(employee.getFathersName());
            this.employeeDetailName.setText(employee.getName());
            this.emloyeeDetailJmbg.setText(employee.getJmbg());
            this.emloyeeDetailPosition.setText(employee.getPosition());
            this.employeeDetailContractType.setText(employee.getContractType());
            this.employeeDetailStatus.setText(employee.getStatus());

        }

        else
        {
            this.employeeDetailLastname.setText("");
            this.emloyeeDetailFathersName.setText("");
            this.employeeDetailName.setText("");
            this.emloyeeDetailJmbg.setText("");
            this.emloyeeDetailPosition.setText("");
            this.employeeDetailContractType.setText("");
            this.employeeDetailStatus.setText("");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the items to the table, the first item becomes selected immediately. This happens before you register the listener with the selection model's selected item property, so the listener's method isn't invoked for that initial selection.

Move the lines

```
  this.employeeModel.loadData();
  employees = this.employeeModel.getEmployees();
  employeeTableView.setItems(employees);
```

to the end of the `initialize()` method, after you register the listener with the selected item.

Comment: Thank you James_D. You are stackoverflow legend :)